# SQL CREATE VIEW

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I HAVE A QUERY LIKE THIS:

```
CREATE VIEW dashboard
AS 
SET @prevValuepo := 0; 
SET @prevValuefc := 0;
SELECT *,po-@prevValuepo AS selisihpo ,@prevValuepo:= po,forecast-@prevValuefc AS selisihfc ,@prevValuefc:= forecast
FROM view_t_dasboard WHERE tahun= '2020' ORDER BY bulan ASC
```

BUT WHY CAN'T CREATE TABLE VIEW

> error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @prevValuepo :=0, @prevValuefc :=0,
> po-@prevValuepo AS selisihpo ,@prevValu' at line 4

Comment: *check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version* what is your server version precisely?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have these `SET` statemments inside the `CREATE VIEW` statement. Also, since the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select` clause is undefined, your query might not even do what you want consistently.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, I would recommend window functions instead of user-defined variables. I think the logic you want is:

```
create view dashboard as
select
    t.*,
    po - lag(po, 1, 0) over(order by bulan) as selisihpo,
    forecast - lag(forecast, 1, 0) over(order by bulan) as selisihfc
from view_t_dasboard t
where tahun= '2020'
```